# UML class operations

Tags: uml

Can somebody help me with this problem, I dont know why there is an `addCustomer()` function in the `Customer` class.

How can a new `Customer` object be created in a `Customer` object? The example is as follows:

```
-------------------
Class Customer     
-------------------
+forename        
+lastname
-------------------
+createCustomer()
-------------------
```

I mean where is the new Customer obejct stored when there are only those 2 attributes ?

Comment: Without the rest of the details, it is impossible for us to tell you why the creator of the UML document did things the way they did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: updated following comment from Alexander Pavlov below (thanks).

Most likely it's a factory method.  So it's a class-based operation rather than instance-based.  Just like in java/c#/etc where class-based ops (e.g. constructor/factory) and instance-based operations are both declared in the class signature.

As with java etc. the `createCustomer()` operation would not be called on an instance.  e.g. (pseudocode)

```
Customer customer1 = Customer.createCustomer();
Customer customer2 = Customer.createCustomer();
customer1.forename = "Jon";
customer1.surname  = "Skeet";
//etc.
```

There used to be a convention in UML that class-based ops start with the '$' symbol to differentiate them from instance-based ops.  However, iirc, it was just a convention, not mandated in the UML spec.  (don't have easy access to the spec just now to check).

hth.

Comment: This is called a factory method rather than a constructor (which may get called by the factory method). http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=21 is the top googled Java-related result on factory methods.

Comment: @Alexander good point.  It's still a static method on the class - so answer is still largely correct.  Will update though.